# passport local-strategy executing the successcase always

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying an example of local-strategy passport. When I do a POST request with incorrect password (I only have a single db record at this moment) it still does ends up executing my success function :

```
function  (err, user) {
    console.log("Login successful");
    res.redirect('/loggedIn');
}
```

defined in passport.authenticate.Where am I going wrong ? When is the failureRedirect invoked.

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var http = require('http');
 var server = http.Server(app);


var querystring = require('querystring');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');

var Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var users = {
  user : {username : "abc", password : "123"},

  findByUsername (username, cb) {
     return cb(null, this.user);
  }
};

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passport.use(new Strategy(
  function verify (username, password, done) {
      users.findByUsername(username, function  (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err);}

        if (!user) {return done(null, false);}

        if (user.password != password) {return done(null, false);}

        return done(null, user);

      });


  } // close verify function


  ));

 app.get('/signupError', function (req, res) {
  var result = {error : 'You entered incorrect username/password'};
    res.status(200).json(result);
 });

  app.get('/loggedIn', function (req, res) {
  var result = {error : 'You entered correct username/password'};
    res.status(200).json(result);
 });

 app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
 passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/signupError' }, 
    function  (err, user) {

    console.log("Login successful");
    res.redirect('/loggedIn');
  })(req,res);
 });

  server.listen(80, function() {
      console.log("listening") ;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this argument in passport.use

```
passport.use( new Strategy({usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    session: false
  },
    function verify (username, password, done) {
  users.findByUsername(username, function  (err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err);}

    if (!user) {return done(null, false);}

    if (user.password != password) {return done(null, false);}

    return done(null, user);

  });
```

Comment: Nope. this does not help.